# Running nestjs microservices in pm2 cluster mode

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pm2

Our application structure looks like

```
[Nestjs App1]                     
Listens on Http Port 8080
Accepts Http Connection from User 

[Nestjs App2]
Listens on Http Port 8081 as Microservice over Transport.TCP

  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8081 }
    },
  );
  await app.listen();
```

App1 receives http requests from user and after authentication check it connects to App2 via nestjs microservice pattern and returns the data computed by App2 to the user.

We are able to run both apps into pm2 cluster mode.

However, for App2, Graceful restart is not handled properly by App2 cluster as during App2 restart, requests are continuously sent to every instance of App2 and fails while some instance of App2 are being bootstrapped.

We suspect, it is due to the working of App2 as microservice which communicates to App1 through node's net socket transport events and pm2 cluster (node cluster) is not able to determine the nature of communication and keeps sending all requests to every instance of App2 even after sending SIGINT while restarting?

Anyone having better understanding of node cluster's requests management and nestjs microservice please help us how to handle graceful restart for nest default(TCP) microservices.

We want that during `pm2 reload App2`, new requests should be sent only to other App2 cluster instances which are currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After through debugging, it is found that default nestjs microservice TCP client does not work properly in cluster mode of pm2 as it communicates with each other using socket events. Graceful restart can't be achieved using default TCP client strategy of nestjs microservice as during graceful restart of microservice, i.e. after SIGINT process event, its socket server keeps accepting new requests and thus graceful restart/stop fails altogether.

We resolved it after implementing our own `CustomTransportStrategy` server and custom `ClientProxy` on the top of HTTP protocol with node's `http` package.
In addition, we keep counter record of all requests in process using global interceptor.

Using, OnApplicationShutdown lifecycle event of nestjs, we return a promise and resolve it after all pending requests are processed by our microservice.
As a fallback, We also set "kill_timeout" of pm2 cluster to a higher value in such a way that it forcefully kills and restart our microservice when something goes wrong.

Now graceful restart is working fine in the pm2 cluster mode using our custom transport strategy over HTTP.